# PHP artisan serve not updating

Tags: php, laravel

I run my laravel-project in Visual Studio Code. Normally what I did was `npm run watch` to watch for changes in vue templates and js files.

Then run `php artisan serve`. Now the server was started, and I could open the site locally.

Now when I run `php aritan serve` I can see the site but when I change something in a .php file (for example components.php), and I reload the site, there are no changes. I can completely delete .php files, nothing changes. What changed?

Comment: It might be a bug or a "dual" update. Did you run `composer update` recently? Run `npm outdated` and see what you get. If webpack is in the list, you may have to update webpack. The same (more or less) occurred to me about a year ago. Updating webpack did the trick.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey i just had a look, webpack is not outdated. Regarding composer update: just tried and did not work, migrated back, does not work either

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear cache and config as well,
you can also try this for running the laravel(to see if it works)

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public/
```

Comment: When i run this, random components disappear